# Twig variable syntax in onclick js function

Tags: javascript, twig, symfony4

I have for example a twig variable:

```
{% set emailmult1= 'op000' %}
```

and I js function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function seleccionartod(emailmult1, estado) {
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i ++)
document["forms"]["emailmultiple"]["op000000"]["checked"] = estado;
document["forms"]["emailmultiple"][emailmult1 + i]["checked"] = estado;
}
</script>
```

This works:

```
<input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="Todos" onclick="seleccionartod( 'op000' , this.checked)"/>
```

but this doesn't works:

```
<input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="Todos" onclick="seleccionartod( {{ emailmult1 }} , this.checked)"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: `{{ emailmult1 }}` simply outputs `op000`, you still need to add single quotes yourself. You might also consider using [proper escaping](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html#escape) for such scenario. Something like that I suppose: `seleccionartod('{{ emailmult1|e('js') }}', this.checked)`.

Comment: The emailmult1 var is a litle more complex: {% set emailmult1= 'op000' ~ t0 ~ c %} but that does not matter. I tried the js escape and escape general, but it doesnt work. The variable and onclick function are inside a for loop.

Comment: The important part is not the escaping but the addition of single quotes around the variable output so that javascript can interpret it as a string.

Comment: The code @AlanT. used in his first commend should work. Hence he used single quotes outside your `twig`: `seleccionartod('{{ emailmult1|e('js') }}', this.checked)`

Comment: Thanks Alan and DarkBee. It works now.